# Is it possible to achieve the WebKit Scrollbar effect in IE?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, webkit, scrollbar

I want to style my custom scrollbar. I know this is possible with WebKit, but is it possible to achieve a similar effect in Internet Explorer?

Comment: @epascarello I asked in general, hoping for a quick answer from someone who is an expert in web development area and knows for sure. If you don't know how to style a WebKit browser scrollbar and need an example, maybe you shouldn't comment in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, yes it's possible, with only browserspecific CSS for IE:

```
BODY {
    background-color          : orange;
    scrollbar-face-color      : red;
    scrollbar-arrow-color     : green;
    scrollbar-track-color     : yellow;
    scrollbar-shadow-color    : pink;
    scrollbar-highlight-color : white;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color   : brown;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-Color: gray;
}
```

You can play around with it. [More details](http://www.spectrum-research.com/v2/projects_scrollbar_generator.asp)

**For more control** there are several JS-Plugins to achieve the same look and feel for IE like in Webkit. I find it difficult to apply these, but here a list of Plugins i think, they're OK:

- [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller)
- [dw_scroll](http://dyn-web.com/code/scroll/demos.php)
- [jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)

A list of similar plugins: http://slodive.com/web-development/jquery-scroll/

To get it work, it's important to set your HTML-Markup as exactly the same as in the examples.

What you can do is, open the example HTML and modify them to your needs. That's the easiest way, i think.

Hope this helps :)