# How to properly apply a CSS hack for Kendo UI grid scroll bar in IE11+

Tags: angular, google-chrome, internet-explorer, kendo-ui

I am creating a grid using Kendo UI grid in Angular for my web application. For scroll bar, i wrote some code and it is working fine in Chrome, but in IE the color, width is not showing properly for the scroll bar.

Below is the sample code for the scroll bar that I have in my CSS file:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar  { width: 10px; height: 10px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button  {  background-color: #dddddd; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track  {  background-color: #e8eaec;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  { background-color: transparent;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb  { height: 50px; background-color: #00AEEF; border-radius: 5px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner  { background-color: #dddddd;}
::-webkit-resizer  { background-color: #dddddd;}
```

How can I resolve this issue in IE11+?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to achieve the WebKit Scrollbar effect in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954475/is-it-possible-to-achieve-the-webkit-scrollbar-effect-in-ie)

Comment: But I can't change the width of the scroll bar with above solution.

Comment: I think u cant achive that in ie without using some js plugins to replace default scrollbars. Question above have some examples of them